# chrome extension popup not showing up

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I was working on a chrome extension but the popup is not showing up when i click the icon.

I have seen some questions saying that the problem was with the `page_action` to be `browser_action`, but when i did that it didn't work and still not showing anything. I am on windows 10, latest chrome version.

Here is my `mainfest.json` file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Key shifter",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "select text then press ctrl + shift + e",
    "icons": {"128":"icon128.png"},
    "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "I dont know what im doing",
    "default_popup:": "popup.html"},
    "permissions": [
    "activeTabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",

  ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide your `popup.html` content. Seem like there is nothing wrong with your manifest.json file

Comment: There's a mistake: `"activeTabs"` should be `"activeTab"`. Open chrome://extensions page and you'll see an error in your extension card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two problems in you manifest,

1. There is extra comma(,) after the last permission
2. default_popup key is not valid, you have given "`default_popup:`" (extra colon) it should be `"default_popup": "popup.html"`

---

Updated manifest

```
    {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Key shifter",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "select text then press ctrl + shift + e",
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "I dont know what im doing",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ]}
```

Comment: thank you it was really the  "default_popup:" that was the main problem , but there were another problems though like the extra comma at the last permission and "activeTabs" must be "activeTab"